# ML Combination of Clustering and Regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, clustering

I recently faced a question that I, strangely, never thought of...

Basically, I am considering a setup in which I want to perform regression on a very rich dataset. The chances to overfit are really high, and I am lead to think that a global model could not work.

So, operatively, I am lead to think that what one could do is to define not a global model, with the aim to fit just **one** single regression model for the whole dataset, but to perform **many** regressions, eventually with different parameters and feature importance, on properly identified clusters.

Said in other words, I am looking for a pipeline to combine a clustering approach to a subsequent ***local*** regression.

My question is: theoretically, are there methods that have been investigated in this direction? I must confess I am not aware of any of them. I always considered the dataset to start with as a whole, and try at best to train a model curing overfitting with the aim to achieve the best in terms of generalization to a test set.

**EDIT**

I am now puzzled in some respects in regard to the fact that ensemble learning such as random forest regression could be regarded, in some respect, as a simultaneous combination of clustering and regression. Indeed, different learners which learn different subsets of the data would highlight different aspects of it and therefore would result in fitting a quite different model for these substantially different parts of the data. Is that correct?

So, eventually, a potential answer to the question is: is ensemble learning anyhow related to learning different learners on (slightly) different subsets/clusters of the data? Of course the big difference is that in ensemble learning the subsets of the data are randomly drawn, and not selected according to some feature distribution. But even coped with this randomness, could some ensemble techniques boil down to ending up with different learners for (stochastically identified across random drawing of the subsamples) clusters? That said, it is true that the ensemble philosophy washes out these differences in that it tries to aggregate the N learners into one, so for very heterogenic datasets could not be the strategy.

But, that said, it would be nice to know whether there is a technique which puts in practice the first part of what I outlined above, i.e. progressive cluster formation based on the performance of a local regression model on the randomly drawn subset of the training data.

Comment: What do you hope to achieve with the clustering?

Comment: Also, look into methods designed for p >> n. Random forests can work well, and also regularisation methods applied to your regression (LASSO, elastic net)

Comment: The clustering would just be an ease to not overfit. So, I hope that when I divide the dataset in clusters, and perform regression of different models on each of the clusters, I achieve a better prediction compared to fitting a model for the whole dataset. I can live with different models existing locally (i.e., different regression models for different clusters).

Comment: I am not sure to well understand the situation. Is the data set made of couple of points such as $(x_k,y_k)$ for $k=1$ to $k=n$, or are there multiple variables ? In the first case, you could replace the overall regression by a piecewise regression with independent  regression in each domain. The main difficulty is to determine the limits of the domains, which then might be arbitrary and so, leading to not robust process.

Comment: In addition to my preceding comment and for information, a non iterative method to determine the limits of the domains is explained in the paper referenced below. They are some examples , but only for two or three domains. More would require specific studies and this would probably be not realistic if the number of domains was large. https://fr.scribd.com/document/380941024/Regression-par-morceaux-Piecewise-Regression-pdf

Comment: The dataset is made of a number of features (right now, five) and a target variable. I understand your point, but I am looking for an automated way to do that: how do I know which are the domains to consider? This are subranges of the possible combination fo the five features for which the prediction of the target variable is (at best) explainable with a local regressor. For instance, I just found this approach (https://papers.nips.cc/paper/3115-a-local-learning-approach-for-clustering.pdf), which goes a bit in this direction.

Comment: OK. In this case, the method that I was thinking of (which can be easily automated without iterative process) is not convenient. Sorry, forget it.

Comment: Have you heard of piecewise regression?

Answer (score 0):

I have heard of the idea of using a random forest which runs a linear regression model at each leaf instead of returning the mean value. Unfortunately I'm struggling to find a good reference, but [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.02312.pdf) mentions the idea citing earlier work [here](http://www.rob-mcculloch.org/some_papers_and_talks/papers/published/cartfinal.pdf).